# Two three digit numbers, from a list of digits, should multiply to 90720

Tags: combinatorics

> You have a list of 6 numbers: 2, 2, 3, 5, 6, and any other one.
>
> You must make two three-digit numbers with these so that when you multiply them you get a number with Integer factorization of 2^5 * 3^4 * 5 * 7.

From what I gathered the answer should be 360 * 252 = 90720

Is it the only answer? Are there other ones?

**How do you get to that answer?**

Comment: I think a good approach to the problem is to check the possible divisors $d$ of $90720$ that have three digits and such that $90720/d$ also has $3$ digits, in order for this to happen we must have $d\geq 100$ and $d\leq 90720/100 = 907.2$.

Comment: There are $33$ three-digit numbers with digits from $2,2,3,5,6$.  How many of them are divisors of $90720$?

Comment: @Henry you think it is better to check those $33$ permutations or to first try to generate the divisors? I am not sure

Comment: @Onir Probably not, but it works.  Alternatively there are $120$ divisors of $90720$ and just over a third of them have three digits. How many of them have suitable three digits?

Comment: Oh darn, I guess it's still a bunch of them. But checking if each one has suitable digits is fast.

Comment: Factor your three digit candidates into primes. When you multiply them you must get your unique factorization. This will limit the choices by a lot.

Comment: A better way is to take your factorization and see how many ways you can break that into two three-digit numbers. Eliminate the ones that can't be made up of your given digits plus the wild card.

Comment: Well computer verification shows that's the only solution if it helps :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call the factor that does not have the "special" digit the humble factor.

If the humble factor is not a multiple of $3$ then it must be a divisor of $2^5\cdot5\cdot7= 1120$. Hence the humble factor must be $1120/10$ or $1120/8$ or $1120/7$ or $1120/5$ or  $1120/4$ or $1120/2$. These numbers are $112, 140, 160, 224, 280, 560$. Each of these numbers has digits we do not have available.

Now notice that in order for the humble factor to be a multiple of $3$ it must be $522
$ or $252$ or $225$ (since the digits we have available are three that are $2\bmod 3$ and two that are $0\bmod 3$).

We can check that only $252$ is a divisor of $90720$ by factoring all three numbers ($29$ divides $522$ and $25$ divides $225$).

Finally we just need to check that $90720/252 = 360$, and so we need the special character to be $0$, but it works.

Comment: In hindsight I think the key observation is that our number is specially divisible by $3$, and divisibility by $3$ is friendly with digit permutation.